# Confidence interval for RMSE

Tags: confidence-interval, rms

I want to estimate 95% C.I. for RMSE(Root mean square error).

However, i have a difficulty in estimating C.I. due to RMSE equation

(there is a root in RMSE equation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach that is common to get [confidence intervals for standard deviation](http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/ci-variances.htm): we get confidence intervals for variance and then just take the square root of the extremes of the interval.

Here you can compute a CI for mean square error and take the square root of the values you get. Since square root is a monotonic growing function, probabilities inside and outside of the interval remain the same.